# MAMP Pro UI is not showing

Tags: user-interface, windows-10, mamp, mamp-pro

My user interface for MAMP Pro itˈself won't show up. . Everything run/works fine though (Apache, MySQL).
I'm on Windows 10 Home 1903. The window is simply not there, also not in Task view.

What i tried so far to no avail;

- Uninstalled MAMP, installed latest package
- Windows + arrowkeys for window positioning
- Other Monitors, extended & mirror view

The normal MAMP UI (not pro) launches fine btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody else experiencing this issue in the future, it has to do with Windows screen management. For me hitting windows + P and selecting extending screen, enter, and than quickly back to 'second screen only' showed the application UI 'ghosting' somewhere in the right below corner.

Somehow like magic the previews in my task view (and also hovering over taskbar icon) were back and the app is showing again.

Comment: Thank you, I've had the same problem. Your information helped me. Thank you very much ;)